# Create a String with Quotes

Tags: python, string

I have a code like -

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
sql_command = "select * from [dbo].[DB_Name] where DT like " + str(today) + '%'
```

But I want my string to look like this -

```
select * from [dbo].[DB_Name] where DT like 'today%'
```

I am strugling to put quotes on the date - it should be '2021-01-11%'.
How can I do it? I have tried to format the today first but i am unable to do it.

Comment: **NEVER** create SQL commands by interpolation! It'll subject you to major security issues! Your library should have a way of declaring and passing in arguments to a SQL-query. This is called a parameterized query. [Here's how you do it with psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NEVER USE STRING INTERPOLATION FOR A SQL-QUERY!**

All SQL languages has a way to pass in *parameterized queries*, i.e. queries along with parameters. This will pre-compile the statement before adding the arguments, making it impossible to do a [SQL-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), the biggest security issue on the web to date.

If you're using psycopg2, you can create your query as a parameterized query by something like this:

```
sql_query = "select * from [dbo].[DB_Name] where DT like '%s%%'"
cursor.execute(sql_query , [today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")])
```

Here, `sql_query` will contain `select * from [dbo].[DB_Name] where DT like '%s%%'`.

The `%s` is where to put in the argument, and the `%%` is to put in a single percentage sign (must use two so the percentage sign isn't confused for the start of a parameter). And also, in Python you can have either `'` or `"` in your string if you just make sure to start with the other of them.

Comment: There are still instances where STRING INTERPOLATION is required i.e. is it not always possible to used a prepared SQL query. Just escape the string before using it,

Comment: @MikeMoy I've yet to see a case where string interpolation is required, as parameterized queries are just string interpolation on a prepared query. To just escape a string isn't a security fix as it requires you to do an full-blown analysis of your query and every possible input. In some cases (like the one above), it's probably not that big of an issue, but there's no reason to add mental overhead and potential security holes into your application when you can do something more secure that requires less mental overhead.

Comment: to give you an example of where it is required lets say I have a field in a database table called carManufacturer. Each row in the table represents a different car manufacturer. 

Now there is a user interface that allows a person to select an individual car manufacturer or selsect multiple car manufacturers. The user also has the option to select "all".

Comment: If the user selects "Toyota" and "Tesla" and "Ford" the sql query would use the IN operator. Note the number of user selections could be more than 3 car manufacturers so the SQL query statement has to be created dynamically, we can not just pass static parameters in a prepared statement.

Comment: @MikeMoy Yes, that's a tricky case. However, string interpolation is not the only option; and even then you would still use a parameterized query but interpolate just the arguments. Other solutions would be to use a stored procedure, or to batch a certain amount of statically prepared queries. Like many times in programming, there are cases where *never* doesn't apply, but then you should know the ramifications. For example, creating prepared statements dynamically has other problems than security, like exhausting the DB's cache or the potential for user-generated memory errors.

Comment: I don't think you can interpolate just the arguments when creating a prepared statement dynamically

Comment: @MikeMoy No, you're right. What I thought of was that you can create a prepared query in a secure manner, like `'WHERE id IN (' + ', '.join('%s' for _ in range(num)) + ')'` and then pass in the arguments. So while it's created using string interpolation to generate the argument list for the prepared query, the interpolation isn't based on user input, but meta data of the user input.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Ted in the comments, interpolation of commands can cause major security issues such as SQL injections.

Coming over to your query, you can do it by using single-quotes inside double-quotes.

```py
print("'hello'")
```

will print

```py
'hello'
```

Comment: i just want to point out that this solves the query of printing `'something'`. the answer by Ted is the one you should go with if this is what you want with SQL.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about SQL commands by interpretation, and from what I am told **DON'T DO THIS**, but here is how to do what you're asking:

```
"select * from [dbo].[DB_Name] where DT like '" + str(today) + "%'"
```

If you use double quotes for your string definition, you can easily use single quotes for single quotes (the opposite is true too)

Comment: that's overkill. you can just nest single-quotes inside double-quotes. check my answer for an explanation.

Comment: Please never suggest string interpolation for a SQL-query. This does answer the question, but the amount of people using insecure SQL is too high! At least have a huge warning saying **DON'T DO THIS!** SQL-injections is one of the biggest issues on the web to date.